# Use variable from header.js in another file with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to reuse variables between parts of my page.

My `header.js` contains JavaScript for the front part of my `header.html` and some important functions such as verifying user authentication (with Firebase):

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, signOut } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
let userData = null;
onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
    if (user) {
        const userDoc = await getDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid));
        userData = { uid: userDoc.id, ...userDoc.data() };
        elements.userFirstname.textContent = userData.firstname;
    } else {
        elements.loginButton.style.display = "block";
        elements.userDropdown.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

In here, I'm verifying the current user authentication, and using it to search for user information in my Firestore database (to get all the extra informations I need). I store the object in `userData`

I would like to reuse this variable elsewhere in the page. Currently each of my pages have `header.js` as a chunk so I was wondering if I can leverage it to reuse it on the JS file of my page, or if the 2 files are not related at all.

Comment: You can't share a variable between the server and the client, unless you communicate it. You can use JSON and AJAX for example.

Comment: Can you give me some examples? If you had to store `userData` from header.js to use it somewhere else in another js file, how would you do it? I think `localStorage` can be a solution, but this can be manipulated by the user at this point I guess.

Comment: The code you provided, runs in node.js or in the browser? Because firebase authentication can be used on both.

Comment: Everything is done on client side

Comment: you can use `sessionStorage`  instead of `localStorage` but it is not advisable to store sensitive data on the browser. note that only strings (JSON) can be stored.

Comment: I also thought this was not optimal that's why I was looking for another option. I just need to reuse my variable from `header.js` in `index.js`, knowing that both files are chunks loaded together. Maybe I can use an export or something but it's not clear to me. I asked chatGPT and it proposes me using import/export, global variables or a plugin for webpack called ProvidePlugin, but not sure what's the best in my case (this variable `userData` will be written only from header, and will be use across almost all the other js files of the project)